# Laravel Eloquent "Call to undefined relationship"

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I'm trying to set up a relationship in Laravel.

Survey.php:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Survey extends Model
{
    public function survey_questions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SurveyQuestion::class);
    }
}
```

And the SurveyQuestion.php model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class SurveyQuestion extends Model
{
    public function survey()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Survey::class);
    }
}
```

The relationship works one way:

```
>>>$a = SurveyQuestion::with('survey')->get();
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2953
     all: [
       App\SurveyQuestion {#2931
         id: 1,
         survey_id: 2,
         question_id: 1,
         survey: App\Survey {#2967
           id: 2,
           name: "Survey 2",
           created_at: "2020-08-20 18:17:45",
           updated_at: "2020-08-20 18:17:45",
           status: "active",
         },
       },
...
```

But results in an error when trying the other model:

```
>>> $a = Survey::with('survey_questions')->get();
Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/RelationNotFoundException with message 'Call to undefined relationship [survey_questions] on model [App/Survey].'
```

What am I missing? TIA!

Answer (score 0):

Using the provided information, I was unable to reproduce your problem. In fact, it does return the Survey with its question.

```
>>> Survey::with('survey_questions')->get();
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#4095
     all: [
       App\Survey {#4029
         id: "1",
         created_at: "2020-08-26 00:22:23",
         updated_at: "2020-08-26 00:22:23",
         survey_questions: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#4103
           all: [
             App\SurveyQuestion {#4101
               id: "1",
               survey_id: "1",
               created_at: "2020-08-26 00:22:23",
               updated_at: "2020-08-26 00:22:23",
             },
           ],
         },
       },
     ],
   }
```

Could you maybe provide a minimal working example in the form of a Github repository ?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - as it turns out, it was a mix of user error and an unreliable SFTP client.